# Faulty laptop key switches

Tags: motherboard, laptop

I have an old ASUS laptop. It's 15.6", 4GB DDR2, and a 1.6ghz dual core AMD.

It was getting quite hot when I decided to turn it on after a couple of years of non-use. Naturally it was quite dusty, and the internal CPU fan and components were dusty, too. Compressed air was not much help.

So I opened it up. I was *really* surprised at how easy it was to  dissemble compared to my previous experience with the absolute horror reincarnate that is of the Toshiba Satellite series.

There was a black anti-static strip attached to the keyboard which I yanked off. There was also a strip with a chip / silicon layout connected to a particular spot which I also had to yank off (these were attached to the keyboard, I had to remove the keyboard to get in the internal components).

Long story short I cleaned everything and now the loudest thing is not the fan anymore, but the crappy hard drive :-)

However, when I connected it back together (through duct tape mostly, some connectors wouldn't attach to the other parts properly) and some minor repairs I noticed that a few keys were not working on the keyboard. It was the S key, the ` key, the 0 key near the - sign and possibly one or two more.

Those did not work beforehand and I did not expect to fix them, either.

However, I do remember, that, when I opened it up, all the key switches, layouts and internal components attached to the keyboard piece appeared non-damaged and identical.

Yet why do these keys in particular not work? I'm not interested in fixing this laptop (i opened it with the expectation if I f'd something up, it'd be a-OK because it's quite worthless as it is now)

Comment: Dirt under the pads? How about some isopropyl alcohol dripped under the rubber bubbles? Although if they're capacitive sensors that wouldn't matter...

Comment: The keyboards on Acer laptops are almost always the first piece to fail. And at $12 for a replacement they're almost never worth trying to repair.